# Propagate change on recurring event of Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

I changed a recurring event once and when I was prompted if I wanted to propagate the changes I said no.
Some other day, I changed another instance of this same recurring event, but now I need to propagate the changes but the message doesn't prompt anymore.

It appeared a symbol indicating that I modified a recurring event, but I cannot find a way to propagate the changes:

[image: calendar]